# PROC SGPLOT add more color into default when group >12

Tags: colors, sas

I am trying to using PROC SGPLOT to draw a bar graph. Groups are differentiate by color. 
Below is the code I wrote:

```
proc sgplot data=comb(where=(PFS_weeks ne .));
yaxis discreteorder=data;
hbar Pt_Info / response=PFS_weeks group=Diagnosis;
```

The code works fine. However, I have 18 groups but there are only 12 the default group color. So the colors for my group will cycle to the #1 default color from group 13.

My question is, is there a way to increase the number of default group color so that all my groups can have different color?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get colors assigned the way you want is to use attribute maps.  If you're not using them, you're limited to the GRAPHDATAn (1-12) colors, or using GTL (which I highly recommend, but is more than you need here).

Create an attribute map data set, which maps values to colors (or other attributes).  ie:

```
data attrs;
input id $ value $ fillcolor $;
datalines;
Diagnosis 1 Blue
Diagnosis 2 Black
Diagnosis 3 Green
Diagnosis 4 Yellow
;;;;
run;
```

You then call it via

```
proc sgplot data=comb(where=(PFS_weeks ne .)) attrmap=attrs;
yaxis discreteorder=data;
hbar Pt_Info / response=PFS_weeks group=Diagnosis attrid=Diagnosis;
run;
```

The values for `value` need to be the actual labelled values of the variable in question; not the underlying value, but the label if there is any formatting done.  The id, on the other hand, does not have to be identical to the grouping variable.

See [the documentation page on attribute maps](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/65235/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n18szqcwir8q2nn10od9hhdh2ksj.htm) for more detail.